# Issue with imdistline() function in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, distance

I am trying to measure the distance two points on an image and then use that distance as an input for some other function.
Here is my code:

```
figure, imshow(I);
h = imdistline(gca);

api = iptgetapi(h);
width = api.getDistance();
```

When I run it, I am able to drag and get the distance I want on the image, but the distance I get from using the getDistance is some default value it started with , when it opened and it does not change , even if I change it in the image. How can the variable width have the distance i measured before I press enter or any eye and close the image.

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait with the getDistance() function:

```
% create random image
I = rand(100);
figure, imshow(I);
h = imdistline(gca);
api = iptgetapi(h);
% wait for key pressed
pause('on');
pause;
% get line
width = api.getDistance();
disp(width);
```

Now the image appears, you can move your distance measure, then focus matlab console and press any key to get the result.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, it worked, I had one more question, can i measure multiple distances in the same image (I want to measure two of them). how can i do that.

Comment: Just repeat the last lines from `pause` on.

Comment: I mean measure two distances in the image at the same time, not doing it two times.

Comment: I dont know if that is possible. Why not one by one?